# batch renormalization layer keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

I am having problems loading the weights of a trained model in Keras, which consists in the layers provided in the following scheme:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 12, 86, 98,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
zero_padding3d (ZeroPadding3D)  (None, 12, 96, 112,  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d (Conv3D)                 (None, 12, 96, 112,  448         zero_padding3d[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                       (None, 12, 96, 112,  0           zero_padding3d[0][0]             
                                                                 conv3d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 4128        add[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 224         conv3d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 27680       batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 224         conv3d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 27680       batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 224         conv3d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 27680       batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 224         conv3d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 27680       batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 224         conv3d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_6 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 27680       batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 224         conv3d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_7 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 27680       batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 224         conv3d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     (None, 12, 48, 56, 3 0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
                                                                 batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_8 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 16448       add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 448         conv3d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_9 (Conv3D)               (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 110656      batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 448         conv3d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_10 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 110656      batch_normalization_8[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNor (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 448         conv3d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_11 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 110656      batch_normalization_9[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 448         conv3d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_12 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 110656      batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 448         conv3d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_13 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 110656      batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 448         conv3d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_14 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 110656      batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 448         conv3d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_2 (Add)                     (None, 12, 24, 28, 6 0           batch_normalization_13[0][0]     
                                                                 batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_15 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 65664       add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 896         conv3d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_16 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 442496      batch_normalization_14[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 896         conv3d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_17 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 442496      batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 896         conv3d_17[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_18 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 442496      batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 896         conv3d_18[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_19 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 442496      batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 896         conv3d_19[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_20 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 442496      batch_normalization_18[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 896         conv3d_20[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_21 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 442496      batch_normalization_19[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_20 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 896         conv3d_21[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_3 (Add)                     (None, 12, 12, 14, 1 0           batch_normalization_20[0][0]     
                                                                 batch_normalization_14[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_22 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 262400      add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_21 (BatchNo (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 1792        conv3d_22[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_23 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 65792       batch_normalization_21[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_24 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 65792       conv3d_23[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_25 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 65792       conv3d_24[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_26 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 65792       conv3d_25[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_27 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 65792       conv3d_26[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_28 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 65792       conv3d_27[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_4 (Add)                     (None, 12, 6, 7, 256 0           conv3d_28[0][0]                  
                                                                 batch_normalization_21[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose (Conv3DTranspo (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 262400      add_4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 12, 12, 14, 3 0           conv3d_transpose[0][0]           
                                                                 add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_29 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 2654464     concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_22 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1792        conv3d_29[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_30 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1769728     batch_normalization_22[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_23 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1792        conv3d_30[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_31 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1769728     batch_normalization_23[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_24 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1792        conv3d_31[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_32 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1769728     batch_normalization_24[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_25 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1792        conv3d_32[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_33 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1769728     batch_normalization_25[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_26 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1792        conv3d_33[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_34 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1769728     batch_normalization_26[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_27 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 1792        conv3d_34[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_5 (Add)                     (None, 12, 12, 14, 2 0           batch_normalization_27[0][0]     
                                                                 conv3d_transpose[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_1 (Conv3DTrans (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 131200      add_5[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 0           conv3d_transpose_1[0][0]         
                                                                 add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_35 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 663680      concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_28 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 896         conv3d_35[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_36 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 442496      batch_normalization_28[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_29 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 896         conv3d_36[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_37 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 442496      batch_normalization_29[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_30 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 896         conv3d_37[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_38 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 442496      batch_normalization_30[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_31 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 896         conv3d_38[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_39 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 442496      batch_normalization_31[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_32 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 896         conv3d_39[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_40 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 442496      batch_normalization_32[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_33 (BatchNo (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 896         conv3d_40[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_6 (Add)                     (None, 12, 24, 28, 1 0           batch_normalization_33[0][0]     
                                                                 conv3d_transpose_1[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_2 (Conv3DTrans (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 32832       add_6[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 12, 48, 56, 9 0           conv3d_transpose_2[0][0]         
                                                                 add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_41 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 165952      concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_34 (BatchNo (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 448         conv3d_41[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_42 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 110656      batch_normalization_34[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_35 (BatchNo (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 448         conv3d_42[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_43 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 110656      batch_normalization_35[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_36 (BatchNo (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 448         conv3d_43[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_44 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 110656      batch_normalization_36[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_37 (BatchNo (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 448         conv3d_44[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_45 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 110656      batch_normalization_37[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_38 (BatchNo (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 448         conv3d_45[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_46 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 110656      batch_normalization_38[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_39 (BatchNo (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 448         conv3d_46[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_7 (Add)                     (None, 12, 48, 56, 6 0           batch_normalization_39[0][0]     
                                                                 conv3d_transpose_2[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_3 (Conv3DTrans (None, 12, 96, 112,  8224        add_7[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_47 (Conv3D)              (None, 12, 96, 112,  33          conv3d_transpose_3[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
y_true (InputLayer)             [(None, 12, 86, 98,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cropping3d (Cropping3D)         (None, 12, 86, 98, 1 0           conv3d_47[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 ()                   0           y_true[0][0]                     
                                                                 cropping3d[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_loss (AddLoss)              ()                   0           lambda[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 19,793,601
Trainable params: 19,771,041
Non-trainable params: 22,560
```

It is the same model, but I am not entirely sure why I get thrown the following error:

```
  File "/projects/.../.../projects/.../.../model/web_app.py", line 177, in generate_mask
    model.load_weights(path + '/.../vnet_46.h5', by_name = False)
  File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 162, in load_weights
    return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
  File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1424, in load_weights
    saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
  File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 757, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    str(len(weight_values)) + ' elements.')
ValueError: Layer #2 (named "batch_normalization" in the current model) was found to correspond to layer batch_normalization in the save file. However the new layer batch_normalization expects 8 weights, but the saved weights have 7 elements.
```

I am using tensorflow v1.14.0 and I believe it could be related to the tensorflow version.

Comment: We will need more than just the ValueError statement to help you solve this. Please reread [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: This feels like the model in the saved file does not match with the model loaded into memory.

Comment: You have received above because model was saved in Keras and then tried to load on different versions of Keras/Tensorflow. To fix your issue, can you try to save and load using the same version of keras/tensorflow. Thanks!